# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using this code as a base and wish to view the learning progress by the loss within Tensorboard. After adding the writer and attempting to add_summary, I receive the above error presented within the title.

```
""" Convolutional Neural Network.

Build and train a convolutional neural network with TensorFlow.
This example is using the MNIST database of handwritten digits
(http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

Author: Aymeric Damien
Project: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/
"""

from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tensorflow as tf

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Training Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
num_steps = 200
batch_size = 128
display_step = 10

# Network Parameters
num_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
num_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
dropout = 0.75 # Dropout, probability to keep units

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # dropout (keep probability)


# Create some wrappers for simplicity
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    # MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')


# Create model
def conv_net(x, weights, biases, dropout):
    # MNIST data input is a 1-D vector of 784 features (28*28 pixels)
    # Reshape to match picture format [Height x Width x Channel]
    # Tensor input become 4-D: [Batch Size, Height, Width, Channel]
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Convolution Layer
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Apply Dropout
    fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    # Output, class prediction
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
    # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
}

# Construct model
logits = conv_net(X, weights, biases, keep_prob)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)


# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    for step in range(1, num_steps+1):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.8})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                 Y: batch_y,
                                                                 keep_prob: 1.0})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for 256 MNIST test images
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images[:256],
                                      Y: mnist.test.labels[:256],
                                      keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Running it works completely fine, I then added the writer variable to write to the root tmp directory of my OS.

```
# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/log/", graph=sess.graph)

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)

    for step in range(1, num_steps+1):
        batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.8})
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            summary, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                                 Y: batch_y,
                                                                 keep_prob: 1.0})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.4f}".format(summary) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.3f}".format(acc))

            writer.add_summary(summary=summary, global_step=step)
            writer.flush()
        writer.close()

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for 256 MNIST test images
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images[:256],
                                      Y: mnist.test.labels[:256],
                                      keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

But that's when the error occurs. What exactly am I doing wrong and what is the correction that needs to be applied to fix this. I'm still quite new to Tensorflow but I've used summary writer before without this error.

I also used this tutorial as well in hopes of fixing this issue:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard

Error just so everyone knows the culprit

```
Step 1, Minibatch Loss= 98733.8750, Training Accuracy= 0.102
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convolutional_network_raw.py", line 137, in <module>
    writer.add_summary(summary=summary, global_step=step)
  File "/home/kyle/.conda/envs/csc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 126, in add_summary
    for value in summary.value:
AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The summary that goes into the file writer is a `tf.Summary` object.  You need to first convert the loss value into a summary object, for example below (also change the variable in the print so you don't get an error):

```
        loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                             Y: batch_y,
                                                             keep_prob: 1.0})
        summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag="loss", simple_value=loss)])
        print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
              "{:.4f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
              "{:.3f}".format(acc))
```